# Change from (local) windows authentication to ADFS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, adfs

At least I think I mean ADFS?!
ok so I have created and deployed a simple asp.net web app that staff use.
It uses windows authentication. The windows account is local to the server as this server is in the DMZ.
This works fine but has become more popular that I thought and is now being used across the Organisation.

Obviously I now have an issue whereby any staff that leave the organisation will still have access to this web app. Not good! Rather than have a whole new forms based account management system I though ADFS may be the answer. This is not my area of expertise so bear with me if I go up the wrong road or use nonsense jargon. Our AD is on premise but we sync this to the MS cloud so we can use NT accounts for 365 apps and SSO for a 3rd party web based product. I would like my web app to do the same as the 3rd party web based app.
I have Googled plenty but soon get lost among the ADFS/OWIN/OAuth speak.

If I knew the exact search term to fit my scenario I could go back to my research... If someone could point me to an article that shows how to do *exactly* what I need without me having to do a crash course on SAML etc that would be awesome too.

Comment: https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, agree on on/off-boarding policy, ADFS will not fix that since ADFS authenticates against AD. Neither will Azure AD.

You can go two ways:

Install ADFS. Then you get SSO across all apps. But rather go with Azure AD.

Use Azure AD. Your users are already synched up to Azure AD for O365.

You can use OpenID Connect rather than SAML.

There are a number of samples to guide you [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/).

Comment: I just checked our Azure portal and looked under Enterprise Applications. We already have apps in here that use SSO.  Specifically this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/promapp-tutorial
So basically I need to weave the ability to do "this" into my existing asp.net web app

Comment: @rbrayb: The new nickname confused me for a while but the old icon is still there. Regards :)

Comment: @Penfold That link is for SAML. It's much easier to use one of the samples I linked to and connect these via App Registration. This uses OpenID Connect. But up to you!

Comment: @WiktorZychla Hi! Yes I'm aligning all my user names

Answer (score -1):

Think you want to still use windows authentication but instead of local accounts create and use domain user accounts. The DC will be able to validate accordingly. As far as staff leaving and still having access you need a policy in place which disables/deletes the user account object in the AD when they leave the company so the account no longer exists or is enabled.

Comment: It was stated this server is in a DMZ - this would seem to preclude the use of a domain controller.

Comment: Don't you mention you sync to cloud? Can you have the server in the cloud do it?

Comment: No, I didn't mention that because I'm not the one that asked the question. I'm just pointing out that being in a DMZ normally means you can't access services inside the firewall, such as a domain controller.